# Convert struct to base class

Tags: go

In my understanding, there is no inherent and polymorphism in golang, so how to get the sub-struct from a given struct? For example, struct A has several attributes:

```
type A struct {
    a int
    b string
    c *float64
    d []byte
    e map[string]interface{}
}
```

I want to delete the `e`:

```
type B struct {
    a int
    b string
    c *float64
    d []byte
}
```

So is there any way to convert A to B except copy variables one by one?

Comment: You can compose `B` in `A`. Then assign or copy `A.B` to the new `B` instance

Comment: @nos you're right, so this is the only way to solve the inherent?

Comment: There is polymorphism in go it's just not through inheritance.  Instead you have different structs implement the same interface.  This has some advantages as inheritance can be restrictive as you can either only have one supertype or have to solve the "diamond problem"

Comment: You cannot convert anything in Go to a "base class", because there are no classes in Go.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with embedded fields.  See Struct Types in the [Go Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), e.g.:

> Field names may be specified explicitly (IdentifierList) or implicitly (EmbeddedField).

With an embedded field, you can copy the fields in one struct to the struct in which it is an embedded field with a simple assignment to the field.

Here's a complete, runnable example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Shared struct {
    Id   int
    Name string
}

type A struct {
    Count int
    Shared
}

type B struct {
    Color string
    Shared
}

func main() {
    shared := Shared{
        Id:   1,
        Name: "john",
    }
    a := A{
        Count:  5,
        Shared: shared,
    }
    b := B{
        Color: "green",
    }
    b.Shared = a.Shared
    c := map[string]interface{}{
        `a`: a,
        `b`: b,
    }
    msg, err := json.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Marshal error: %s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(msg))
}
```

Prints:

```
{"a":{"Count":5,"Id":1,"Name":"john"},"b":{"Color":"green","Id":1,"Name":"john"}}
```